# Securing a password/string in source code

Tags: java, android

I have created an application where I could send a mail with Mail API. Therefore, for that I had to provide the email id and password of the source mailbox.

Refer the code below:

```
Mail sender = new Mail("sourceEmailID", "sourcePassword");
sender.sendMail("Subject","Body","sourceEmailID", "destinationEmailID");
```

Now, I dont want to provide the harcoded password inside my source code. Infact I want to convert it into asterisk form or any other secured form.

But the value shouldn't change when calling the original form.

What should I do to for this!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you talking about gmail api?

Answer (score 1):

You will need the plain text password in any case while creating `Mail` Object.
To improve security,
you should:

- Encrypt the password and keep it in code/property file/database. Also store the secret key in code/property file/database. Decrypt it at the time of creating `Mail` object
- Use SSL/TLS/https

This should provide you enough security.